# angular how to reload a controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a categoriesPanel controller that on ng-click I want to show all the products belongings to that category inside my ng-controller productsPanel. The problem im having is that every time I click on the ng-click="selectorCategory" I get the all the products in the clicked category after I refresh the page.

```
     <div class="col-md-6 m-t-10" ng-controller="productsPanel" style="padding-right:1px;">
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="height: 700px">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div ng-repeat="product in Products" class="productRow">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-white btn-xlarge btn-block">{{product.Product}}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 m-t-10" ng-controller="categoriesPanel" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 5px">
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="height: 700px">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div ng-repeat="category in Categories" class="categoryRow">
                    <a href="javascript:;" data-id="{{category.CategoryId}}" ng-click="selectedCategory($event)" class="btn btn-white btn-xlarge btn-block">{{category.Category}}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my angular script that is getting the right data from the backend but the data only shows in the producsPanel controller when i refresh the page. I want to data to show as soon as you do the ng-click.

```
app.controller('categoriesPanel', function($scope, $location, $http, $localStorage){

var CompanyId = $localStorage.Employee[0].CompanyId;

$http({
    method  : 'GET',
    url     : 'http://localhost:8888/categories/ajax_getCompaniesCategories',
    params: {CompanyId: CompanyId}
})
.success(function(data){
    $scope.Categories = data;
    $localStorage.Categories =  data;
});

$scope.selectedCategory = function(event){

    $localStorage.CategoryId = $(event.target).data('id');

    $http({
        method  : 'GET',
        url     : 'http://localhost:8888/products/ajax_getCategoryProducts',
        params: {CategoryId: $localStorage.CategoryId}
    })
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.Products = data;
        $localStorage.Products =  data;

    });
}

});

app.controller('productsPanel', function($scope, $location, $http, $localStorage){
$scope.Products = $localStorage.Products;
});

/* END CONTROLLERS */
```

Comment: sound slike using a routeParam would be better than using a function...then on page reload you have what is needed in the url to filter the data

Comment: who would u use the routeParam in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the product array you are pointing to gets clear when call to getcategoryproducts is made. Can you fix your callback for `ajax_getCategoryProducts` and change success to push elements into the array instead of reassignment.

```
.success(function(data){
        $scope.Products.length=0;
        data.forEach(function(p) { 
           $scope.Products.push(p);
        });
        $localStorage.Products =  $scope.Products;

    });
```

Comment: the product array is not getting clear. I feel that i need to manipulated the dom some how to show the new data.